# Creating First Admin in Node.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design

I've created my first Node.js API and now I am at the step where I need to have initial admin when I push the code live.

My app works the way that there is one admin which can send invitations to users and users can register only with that invitation. My model looks like this:

```
var userSchema  = new Schema({
    "email" : { type: String, unique: true },
    "pass" : { type: String, required: true },
    "type" : { type: String, required: true },
    "invitation" : String
});
```

Field `type` can have a value `admin` or `regular`. For each user creation, email/invitation check is done so users can't be created without invitation.

One of my thought was to have a check each time when database opens:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
  // get all users
  User.find({}, function(err, data){
    // if there are no users at all, create first admin
  });
});
```

Credentials for first admin I would keep in env variables and fetch them like this:

```
var firstAdminEmail = process.env.FIRST_ADMIN_EMAIL;
var firstAdminPass = process.env.FIRST_ADMIN_PASS;
```

To prevent invitation check in user creation, I would create a separate function which would ignore invitation in user creation.

What do you think about this? What would be the best practice for creating that first admin?

Comment: That really depends on how you want the first account to be created. Usually the owner of the application is the owner and he can invite others meaning you will always have that first account but then again that depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey @user3339562! One tip, don't use the word "type" in your schemas because mongoose internally uses "type" to describe the variables types, like `type : String`. Change to "userType" or something else.